# What do the components in Qualified Dividends and Capital Gain Tax Worksheet in instructions of Form 1040 mean?

Tags: united-states, taxes, investing, form-1040

[Qualified Dividends and Capital Gain Tax Worksheet—Line 44](https://apps.irs.gov/app/vita/content/globalmedia/capital_gain_tax_worksheet_1040i.pdf) in the instructions of Form 1040 calculates the tax on the taxable income by

- first decomposing the taxable income in line 1 into  lines 7, 11, 19, and 22,
- then taxing on them at different tax rates of regular tax rate, 0, 0.15, and 0.20. The resulted taxes are in lines 20, 23 and 24.
- finally summing their taxes into line 25

I wonder what the amounts in lines 7,11, 19, and 22 mean?

My purpose is to

- understand which part of the taxable income is taxed at which tax rate, and
- sort the different parts of the taxable income according to their tax rates, and
- find out which parts have relative high tax rates, and which have low tax rates.

Thanks.

p.s.

Do you agree that the worksheet was written like a computer program with little readability, e.g. no suggestive names for most lines?

What are some ways for us to understand the worksheet?

Comment: Yes, the worksheet plus it's instructions can be thought of as a program, though a spreadsheet would be a closer analogy and in fact Zbefore commercial tax software some of us used to translate the forms into spreadsheets for our own convenience.

Comment: Can you show me the spreadsheets converted from the two worksheets?

Comment: Haven't done that exercise in a decade or two. Easier to buy a commercial package which has already implemented that.

Comment: What do you mean by spreadsheets? How are they more convenient for you to understand the worksheets?

Comment: @Derek_6424246 can you kindly educate me how the two posts of understanding these two worksheets are duplicates? Can I suppose you understand the two worksheets very well to the point that you are able to answer the two posts?

Comment: [Excel 1040](https://sites.google.com/site/excel1040/) has the entire tax return form and many worksheets in a spreadsheet. Tab "Line 44" contains this worksheet.